# Patterns using for loops

Tags: java, nested, nested-loops

I am supposed to create this pattern based on the number a user enters. The number the user enters corresponds to the number of rows and stars in each row.

```
    * 
   ** 
  *** 
 **** 
*****
```

I was told to only use nested for loops and cannot use printf(). This is only part of the code that I am working on.

```
for (int row = 1; row <= size; row++) {
            for (int column = 1; column <row; column++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for (int column = 1; column <= row; column++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();

    }
```

I cannot seem to make my output as shown above. Instead I get this:

```
*
 **
  ***
   ****
    *****
```

Could someone give me a hint as to what I am supposed to do? I have spent 2 hours but still can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each row, you should output maximum `size` characters; so if size = 5, on third row, if output three stars, then you need `size-row` spaces => 5 - 3 = 2.

In code:

```
for (int row = 1; row <= size; row++) {
    for (int column = 1; column <= size-row; column++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    for (int column = 1; column <= row; column++) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Sample: http://ideone.com/hC5HDQ

Answer (score 0):

You want to start with more spaces, then remove them until there is not more left. But while removing spaces, you also want to add and additional " * ". So for every space removed you will add an " * "

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
int i=5;

do{
    int j=5;

    while(j>i){
        System.out.print("*");
        j--;
    }
    System.out.println();
    i--;

}while(i>0);
```